# ASP.net core View does not return value to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

What I am trying to achieve is 2 things:

1. send a value I get from an external source (An API) inside my controller for processing. "to check if that ID exists in my database. if not add it" but my issue is that I always get null when I do so. the ID is always empty even though I can view it inside the view. but even with empty id, I should be able to search my database.
2. that's where my second problem comes InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MoviesDB.Models.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'MoviesDB.Controllers.HomeController'.

So in Summary my  View never sends my Controller the ID. and I also get this other error when I try to access my database. (this error happens on startup without me even trying to access that part of the functions)

My view is something like that. I'll only post the affected: so what happens here. my list loads exactly as expected and shows everything I need. after I click on Details and Access my controller it will not give me a value. I will explain later in the other block of code

```
  <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Search)
            {
                @item.Runtime
                //       each table row is assigned with the imdbID returned from the API. if the user clicks one of the rows
                //then the system will 1st check the database if this movie exist in the database. if not then it will be added and then desplayed
                //if the movie exist then it will be automatically desplayed to the user without making another API call.
                <tr >
                    <td><img src="@item.Poster" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" width="200"> </td>
                    <td>@item.Title</td>
                    <td>@item.Year @item.imdbID</td>
                    <td>  <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="FindMovie" asp-for="@item.imdbID">Details </a> </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
```

So what is happening here once I start up my project I will get that error :

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> 'MoviesDB.Models.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate
> 'MoviesDB.Controllers.HomeController'.

I don't know why this is happening, I will post my services on the next block just in case there is something I am missing in there.  well now if I commented out all the database things and just have inside `FindMovie` action

```
Console.WriteLine("I am in Find" + imdbID);
```

I will only get "I am in Find" but I will not have an id next to it. so as it seems I am not sending the ID

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
[BindProperty]
 public Movies movies { get; set; }
 public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext db)
 {
     _db = db;
}
  
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult FindMovie()
{
    return View();
}


[HttpPost]

public IActionResult FindMovie(string imdbID)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("I am in Find" + imdbID);
     var item = _db.Movies.Where(s => s.imdbID.Equals(imdbID)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (item != null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
   return Content("Id is: {imdbID}");
}
```

and lastly here are my services:

```
 services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddRazorPages();
```

Comment: your problem is `Unable to resolve service for type` your controller can not resolve the DbContext. I suggest you create new empty project and setup db against tutorial and check differences between your app and new one.

Comment: but I can access DB to add user with identity . and that project already took me a few days to create , I would not want to start all over again. from what I gather my problem is within services. but I cant fegure out how to fix it.
Edit: Also I am not following some sort of tutorial

Comment: I not mean rewrite new app but only simulate working dbContext on new empty project and check differences agaist your. https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: also possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320189/asp-net-core-2-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-entityframeworkcore

Comment: Hi I am gonna check out the possible dublicate and then if nothing works doing your suggestion. and let you know once I am done. it might take me around 30mins i believe

Answer (score 0):

I have found what the problem was.  When creating a new project with visual studio.
if you choose to create Authentication , it will create a dbcontext for you inside a folder called Data. it so happened this file to be called ApplicationDbContext  as well. out of coincidence I named it the same.

what I did to resolve the error was to rename my own ApplicationDbContext to something new and add it in services and it worked perfectly. it was a structure error I guess.