# "There was an error running the selected code: 'Unable to resolve service for type"

Tags: visual-studio

I'm getting this error while creating a controller in .NET 5
Please help me resolve this ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tr0OE.png)

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320189/asp-net-core-2-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-entityframeworkcore) link can solve your problem as I think. It seems like you forgot to add something in your collection of service. Check the solution, if it doesn't work let me know your feedback.