# Why am I getting this error in ASP.NET Core 6 C#?

Tags: c#

When I want to create a controller I get this error:

[image: error image]

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
> 'Unable to resolve service for type
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Db.ContextOptions'1[DATAMain.DB] while attempting to activate 'DataMain.DB'

DB.cs

```cs
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
        using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
        using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Threading.Tasks;
        
        namespace DataMain
        {
            public class DB : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string>
            {
                public DB(DbContextOptions<DB> options) : base(options)
                {
                }

                public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Have you registed your DbContext as a service?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Unable to resolve service for type ¨Microsoft.entityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions¨1\[LibraryData.LibraryContext\] while attempting to activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70273434/unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-%c2%a8microsoft-entityframeworkcore-dbcontextopti)

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320189/asp-net-core-2-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-microsoft-entityframeworkcore)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore package installed.

then register the service :

```
using ContosoUniversity.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace ContosoUniversity
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
    -->     services.AddDbContext<SchoolContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

   -->      services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }
```

read documentation on microsoft : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: It doesn't work due to a logical error in the framework version, it works fine with net 5.0