# How do I resolve the service for a type during an Entity Framework Core database update?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to initialize a PostgreSQL database by running existing database migrations for .fmbot. I made an MVCE for the purposes of this question but here's the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/fmbot-discord/fmbot) for reference.

Here's my file structure:

[image: FMBot.Bot and FMBot.Persistence.EntityFrameWork as two separate projects]

Here is my stripped down class for handling database migrations in the `FMBot.Persistence.EntityFrameWork` project. This builds with only warnings and has no underlined errors in Visual Studio:

**FMBotDbContext.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace FMBot.Persistence.EntityFrameWork
{
    public class FMBotDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public FMBotDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("configuration is ", configuration);
            this._configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(this._configuration["Database:ConnectionString"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code in Startup.cs I expect would enable `FMBotDbContext` to be instantiated when needed.

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddDbContextFactory<FMBotDbContext>(optionsBuilder =>
    optionsBuilder
        .UseNpgsql(this.Configuration["Database:ConnectionString"])
        .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention()
    );
```

However if I comment out this code I get the same result when I run the update command below. I suspect I need to add more to Startup.cs but I have no idea what it would be.

I am using this command with the intent that it will run all the migrations and set up the database to be populated with data:

```
Update-Database -verbose -project FMBot.Persistence.EntityFrameWork -Startup FMBot.Bot -Context FMBotDbContext
```

However when I run this command I get the following error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'FMBotDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' while attempting to activate 'FMBot.Persistence.EntityFrameWork.FMBotDbContext'.
>
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type type)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.b__13()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.<>c__DisplayClass21_4.b__13()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)

I believe this is because something (that I can't see or edit but is triggered by the command?) is trying to call the `FMBotDbContext` constructor but is having issues with the type of the `configuration` object matching `IConfiguration`, but this is where I'm stuck.

I've spent two days trying to figure this out but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm open to changing any stage of my approach. I'm new to .NET and Visual Studio with most of my experience being with Node if that helps you understand my thought process.

The project maintainer's solution to this problem is to paste in hardcoded configuration values when initializing the database, which I'm trying to avoid.

How to I resolve this error?

Comment: Have you read the page linked in the error? That should be your starting point. You haven't posted your `Startup` class which is going to be important in finding the issue. From the documentation link "The DbContext itself and any dependencies in its constructor need to be registered as services in the application's service provider. This can be easily achieved by having a constructor on the `DbContext` that takes an instance of `DbContextOptions<TContext>` as an argument and using the `AddDbContext<TContext>` method."

Comment: Also the repository you linked to literally has a comment telling you what to do: https://github.com/fmbot-discord/fmbot/blob/5df8da7f59c3142dc745c11481129a5f809e99b3/src/FMBot.Persistence.EntityFrameWork/FMBotDbContext.cs#L61

Comment: @SBFrancies I made a note of the maintainer's solution in my question but surely temporarily hardcoding database connection values is not something that the designers of .NET had in mind?

Comment: @SBFrancies regarding your previous comment the service is registered in the original code with `services.AddDbContextFactory<FMBotDbContext>(b =>
            b.UseNpgsql(this.Configuration["Database:ConnectionString"]));`. however since I could duplicate the error without that line I assumed it was unrelated. so maybe the problem lies in that file?

Comment: It's an odd pattern, I can't say why they have chosen it. Will put my suggestion into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Caveat, I haven't tested this, but I'd suggest the following steps:

1. Remove the `OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)` method from your `FMBotDbContext` class entirely.
2. Remove the current constructor in the `FMBotDbContext` class and replace it with this:

> ```
> public FMBotDbContext(DbContextOptions<FMBotDbContext> options)
>     : base(options)
> {
> }
> ```

3. If you want to use snake case change your `Startup` to configure it there.

> ```
> services.AddDbContextFactory<FMBotDbContext>(b =>
>             {
>           b.UseNpgsql(this.Configuration["Database:ConnectionString"]);
>           b.UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
>             });
> ```

Comment: I think this is a good step in the right direction. I am now getting a similar error as before only instead of being able to resolve service for type `IConfiguration` it can't resolve service for type `'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions\`1[FMBot.Persistence.EntityFrameWork.FMBotDbContext]'`. when it says it "can't resolve service" does that mean the `AddDbContextFactory` call failed? it hasn't been throwing an error...

Comment: What command are you running to generate the migrations? Are you specifying the startup project?

Comment: the command I'm running is in the original question. I specify both the startup project and the project that has the migrations as well as my class that implements `DbContext`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. In your question you use `-Startup FMBot.Bot` - I think that should be `-StartupProject FMBot.Bot`

Comment: I believe `-Startup` is supported as an alias for `-StartupProject`. I tried it anyway though and got the same result

Comment: Huh, the only thing I can possibly think of is that `AddDbContextFactory` isn't a supported design time pattern - maybe try changing it to `AddDbContext` - grasping at straws though really.